# Error. How can i make live table update and delete using ajax in laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, live, insert-update

i try to make editable role in user table but its error and not update data to database

here the error

[image]

this is my blade

```
<div class="table-responsive">
        @csrf
        <table id="editable" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>First Name</th>
              <th>Email</th>
              <th>Role</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            @foreach($allusers as $row)
            <tr>
              <td>{{ $row->id }}</td>
              <td>{{ $row->name }}</td>
              <td>{{ $row->email }}</td>
              <td>{{ $row->role }}</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
```

and here my controller route

```
Route::post('tabledit/action', 'App\Http\Controllers\EventController@action')->name('tabledit.action');
```

and here my function inside EventController

```
function action(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax())
    {
        if($request->action == 'edit')
        {
      $data = $request->role;
      $updaterole = DB::table('users')
                ->where('id', $request->id)
        ->first();

        $updaterole = $data;
        $update->update();

        }

        if($request->action == 'delete')
        {
            DB::table('users')
                ->where('id', $request->id)
                ->delete();
        }
        return response()->json($request);
    }
}
```

and here my view
[image]

can someone pls help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to use if request has instead of request action.

```
if($request->has('edit')
{
//
}
```

### But i didn't change it. Only edited update section.

```
function action(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->ajax())
        {
            if($request->action == 'edit')
            {
          $data = $request->role;
          DB::table('users')->where('id', $request->id)->update(['role' => $data]);
            }
    
            if($request->action == 'delete')
            {
                DB::table('users')->where('id', $request->id)->delete();
            }
            return response()->json($request);
        }
    }
```